# Warnings about peer dependencies when running npm install

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm, warnings

I'm trying to update my React/Firebase project with

```
npm install --save firebase-functions@latest
```

and I get a lot of warnings:

```
npm WARN google-maps-react@2.0.0 requires a peer of react@~0.14.8 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN google-maps-react@2.0.0 requires a peer of react-dom@~0.14.8 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN firebase-functions@1.0.1 requires a peer of firebase-admin@~5.12.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

I'm a newbie so not sure which command should I run to fix the warnings.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Install it by hand:

With npm 5.0.0 or above (edited):

```
npm install react@^16.0.0
npm install react-dom@^16.0.0
npm install firebase-admin@~5.12.0
npm install firebase-functions@latest
```

Before npm 5.0.0 (original):

```
npm install --save react@^16.0.0
npm install --save react-dom@^16.0.0
npm install --save firebase-admin@~5.12.0
npm install --save firebase-functions@latest
```

Comment: Could you please explain why this happens? Why doesn't it just install its dependencies?

Comment: Because firebase-admin is declared as a peer dependency on firebase-functions. See its [package.json](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/blob/master/package.json) on line 54. They are not installed automatically.

Comment: As of npm 5.0.0, installed modules are added as a dependency by default, so the `--save` option is no longer needed.